# Error al intentar hacer un JWT con spring boot mysql angular

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, java-8

tengo un problema con mi backend estoy haciendo un proyecto de clase y necesito ayuda me sale un error que no entiendo porque me ocurre, estoy siguiendo la siguiente pagina como guia.
https://inezpre5.wordpress.com/2019/04/15/jwt-con-spring-boot-mysql-y-angular-7-capitulo-3-rest-service-simple/

Para ello pondre lo que tengo por ahora:

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.dto.Mensaje;
import com.example.demo.models.Juego;
import com.example.demo.service.JuegoService;

@RequestMapping("/front-end/juegos")
public class JuegoController {

    @Autowired
    JuegoService juegoService;

    @GetMapping("/lista")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Juego>> getLista() {
        List<Juego> lista = juegoService.getAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Juego>>(lista, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/detalle/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getOne(@PathVariable int id) {
        if (!juegoService.existePorId(id))
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("no existe ese producto"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        Juego juego = juegoService.getId(id).get();
        return new ResponseEntity<Juego>(juego, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("nuevo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Juego juego) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(juego.getNombre()))
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("el nombre es obligatorio"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if ((Integer) juego.getPrecio() == null || juego.getPrecio() == 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("el precio es obligatorio"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if (juegoService.existePorNombre(juego.getNombre()))
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("ese nombre ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        juegoService.guardar(juego);
        return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("producto guardado"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/actualizar/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Juego juego, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        if (!juegoService.existePorId(id))
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("no existe ese producto"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(juego.getNombre()))
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("el nombre es obligatorio"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if ((Integer) juego.getPrecio() == null || juego.getPrecio() == 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("el precio es obligatorio"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if ((Integer) juego.getDescuento() == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("si el juego no tiene descuento escriba 0"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        if (juego.getGenero() == null || juego.getGenero() == "")
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("Todos los juegos tienen al menos un genero"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if (juego.getDescripcion() == null || juego.getDescripcion() == "")
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(
                    new Mensaje("Todos los juegos tienen que tener como minimo una breve descripcion"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if (juegoService.existePorNombre(juego.getNombre())
                && juegoService.getNombre(juego.getNombre()).get().getId() != id)
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("ese nombre ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        Juego prodUpdate = juegoService.getId(id).get();
        prodUpdate.setNombre(juego.getNombre());
        prodUpdate.setPrecio(juego.getPrecio());
        prodUpdate.setDescuento(juego.getDescuento());
        prodUpdate.setGenero(juego.getGenero());
        prodUpdate.setDescripcion(juego.getDescripcion());
        juegoService.guardar(prodUpdate);
        return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("producto actualizado"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/borrar/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        if (juegoService.existePorId(id))
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("no existe ese producto"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        juegoService.borrar(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("producto eliminado"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Clase Mensaje encargada de lanzar los errores que leera angular

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

public class Mensaje {
    private String mensaje;

    public Mensaje(String mensaje) {
        super();
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

}
```

Clase Juego que es el modelo de la base de datos

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Entity
@Table(name = "juego")
public class Juego {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;

     @NotBlank
     @Column(unique = true)
     private String nombre;

     @NotNull
     private int precio;

     @NotNull
     private int descuento;

     @NotNull
     private String genero;

     @NotNull
     private String descripcion;


    public Juego(int id, @NotBlank String nombre, @NotNull int precio, @NotNull int descuento, @NotNull String genero,
            String descripcion) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.descuento = descuento;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public int getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }


    public void setPrecio(int precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }


    public int getDescuento() {
        return descuento;
    }


    public void setDescuento(int descuento) {
        this.descuento = descuento;
    }


    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }


    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }


    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }


    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }



}
```

Repository JPA de Juego

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.models.Juego;
@Repository
public interface JuegoRepository extends JpaRepository<Juego, Integer> {

    Optional<Juego> findByNombreJuego(String nombre);
    boolean existsByNombreJuego(String nombre);

}
```

Servicio

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.models.Juego;
import com.example.demo.repository.JuegoRepository;

@Service
public class JuegoService {

    @Autowired
    JuegoRepository juegoRepository;

    /**
     * Metodo para obtener todos los juegos
     * 
     * @return una lista con todos los juegos
     */
    public List<Juego> getAll() {
        List<Juego> lista = juegoRepository.findAll();
        return lista;
    }

    public Optional<Juego> getId(int id) {
        return juegoRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Optional<Juego> getNombre(String nombre) {
        return juegoRepository.findByNombreJuego(nombre);
    }

    public void guardar(Juego juego) {
        juegoRepository.save(juego);

    }

    public void borrar(int id) {
        juegoRepository.deleteById(id);

    }

    public boolean existePorNombre(String nombre) {
        return juegoRepository.existsByNombreJuego(nombre);
    }

    public boolean existePorId(int id) {
        return juegoRepository.existsById(id);
    }

}
```

Error que me lanza la consola de spring boot

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'juegoService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'juegoRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'juegoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean com.example.demo.repository.JuegoRepository.existsByNombreJuego(java.lang.String)! No property juego found for type String! Traversed path: Juego.nombre.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'juegoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean com.example.demo.repository.JuegoRepository.existsByNombreJuego(java.lang.String)! No property juego found for type String! Traversed path: Juego.nombre.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean com.example.demo.repository.JuegoRepository.existsByNombreJuego(java.lang.String)! No property juego found for type String! Traversed path: Juego.nombre.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property juego found for type String! Traversed path: Juego.nombre.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:392) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Es por tus dos métodos personalizados que le agregaste: debes agregarles implementación si los quieres usar, si no bórralos.

Comment: Perdona me podrías decir que clase es la que dices es que no se mucho de spring boot.

Comment: `JuegoRepository`, como verás es una interfaz, así que si no le pones una implementación default a los métodos no va a saber de dónde sacarlos.

Comment: Te está diciendo `existsByNombreJuego(java.lang.String)! No property juego found for type String!`. Hay algún método personalizado donde estás usando algo que no implementaste. Ahí está en el log